# Custom ScrollBar in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, scrollpane

Okay so I've probably watched and read every tutorial available on this subject, and none of them have worked for me, so I'm going to the pros(thats you guys :D) I'm trying to make a custom scroll button/ textfield setup. I have the dynamic textbox, the buttons, here's the code :

```
Down.on(click) = function() {
scrolltext.scroll--;};Up.on(click) = function() {
scrolltext.scroll++;};
```

And I'm getting the error "Target of Assignment must be a reference value"

Any suggestions and/or advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Seems your are using AS2 instead of as3..?

Comment: no, I'm using as3. I'm not really a programmer, I just make stuff look pretty, but every now and then I have to write my own codes and that gets confusing for me.

Comment: have to agree with OXMO456. on(click) looks like AS2 thing. AS3 you do it using Listeners.

Comment: This is definitely as2 code, please post the full source of the code you are debugging / working with

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! I was using the wrong code. Here is what I found made it work:

```
function clickUp(event:MouseEvent):void {
scrolltext.scrollV -=1; } Up.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickUp);function clickDown(event:MouseEvent):void {
scrolltext.scrollV +=1;}  Down.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickDown);
```

Thanks everyone for pointing me in the right direction :)